# Вычислить радиус описанной вокруг области просмотра карты окружности

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты

Необходимо вычислить радиус (в метра или километрах) описанной вокруг области просмотра карты окружности
область просмотра - `map.getBounds()`
центер карты - `map.getCenter()`
Как на основе этих данных описать окружность вокруг `bounds`?

Comment: У Вас уже есть центр, у Вас есть координаты верхнего левого угла. Расстояние между этими двумя точками и будет радиус. Тут правда есть одна маленькая проблема - если область будет близка к полюсу и/или очень большой, то не факт, что получится просто так провести окружность. Земля все таки не плоская, как бы этого некоторым не хотелось

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо, как я сразу не смекнул.... думал сложные формулы и расчеты там... Мне посути рисовать этот круг не надо... всего лишь радиус описанной окружности нужен, для задания критерия поиска в базе. Если оформите ответ, с удовольствием его приму.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас уже есть центр, у Вас есть координаты верхнего левого угла. Расстояние между этими двумя точками и будет радиус. Я бы брал ещё расстояние до нижней правой точки и от этого всего среднее/максимум.

Тут правда есть одна маленькая проблема - если область будет близка к полюсу и/или очень большой, то не факт, что получится просто так провести окружность. Земля все таки не плоская, как бы этого некоторым не хотелось.